# error occurs in reporting services when rendering in excel

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I am using windows file share to distribute a report from reporting services.  The report is to render in Excel, and place the rendered excel file on a shared server.  I get the error: **Failure writing report Report1_@timestamp: An error occurred during rendering of the report.** The report does work when rendering in .cvs,  I tried Excel 2003 but get an error due to the row limitation.  Has anyone seen this before? Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Is the rendering triggered by the user or is it triggered by a service/scheduled task?, also, does rendering the report to a local drive from the caller makes a difference?

Comment: I am also getting this when distributing the report via email.  The report runs fine from Report Manager, but fails when report is generated through a subscription to an email address.